# Getting selector for payload from a variable

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio

For a given payload:

```
{
"a": "Hello world"
}
```

and a variable:
`var test = {"b": "a"}`

I would like to get "Hello world" using the variable test's key, "b".

I tried payload.(test."b") and does not work.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Please search previous questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mule 4: Dataweave: Query a key dynamically based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647552/mule-4-dataweave-query-a-key-dynamically-based-on-a-value)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using dynamic selectors.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test = {"b": "a"}
---
payload[test.b]
```

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate.